# SQL query for punch card report 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to generate a report in csv file from below table.

```
   CARDNO       |      PAYCODE          |               OFFICEPUNCH
  00001210      |       1210            |           6/22/2012 9:49:00 AM     
  00001210      |       1210            |           6/22/2012 7:58:00 PM     
  00001211      |       1211            |           6/23/2012 9:31:00 AM     
  00001211      |       1211            |           6/23/2012 6:12:00 PM
```

It holds the employee punch data, every card punch store in a row, so if a user employee punched its card in morning it will marked as **In time**, but the last punch in same date will be considered as **Out time**,  some time employee punches there card many time. so i need to take first and last punch time.

**The problem**

I want to get a CSV in below format

```
  Date     |  PayCode |   Card No   |   Intime  | Outtime  | Hrs Works
2012-06-22 |  1210    |   00001210  |   9:30    | 18:00    |  7.3 
2012-06-22 |  1211    |   00001211  |   9:30    | 18:00    |  7.3 
2012-06-23 |  1210    |   00001210  |   9:30    | 18:00    |  7.3 
2012-06-23 |  1211    |   00001211  |   9:30    | 18:00    |  7.3 
2012-06-24 |  1210    |   00001210  |   9:30    | 18:00    |  7.3 
2012-06-24 |  1211    |   00001211  |   9:30    | 18:00    |  7.3 
                                                                ... and continue
```

Please help me how I can get above result, I have tried by code but i can;t implement it.

Please post with sql Query.

Comment: You write the header to the streamwriter but you never write the actual rows. Are you asking how to use the streamwriter?

Comment: I want to do the logic part in loop so i can get csv in above format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to do the logic in SQL?

Group by PAYCODE and OFFICEPUNCH (and maybe by OFFICEPUNCH with the time truncated), then you can do a MIN(OFFICEPUNCH) for Time In and MAX(OFFICEPUNCH) for Time Out.

**Edit**

SQL example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), OFFICEPUNCH, 20) AS 'PunchDate'
INTO
    #Date
FROM
    MachineRawPunch
WHERE
    OFFICEPUNCH >= @p_StartDate
AND
    OFFICEPUNCH <= @p_EndDate

SELECT
    #Date.PunchDate AS 'Date',
    TblEmployee.PAYCODE,
    TblEmployee.PRESENTCARDNO AS 'CardNo',
    MIN(CASE MachineRawPunch.ISMANUAL WHEN 'Y' THEN MachineRawPunch.OFFICEPUNCH ELSE CAST(#Date.PunchDate + ' 9:30' AS datetime) END) AS 'TimeIn',
    CASE WHEN MachineRawPunch.ISMANUAL = 'N' THEN CAST(#Date.PunchDate + ' 18:00' AS datetime)
         WHEN MAX(MachineRawPunch.OFFICEPUNCH) > MIN(MachineRawPunch.OFFICEPUNCH)
         THEN MAX(MachineRawPunch.OFFICEPUNCH)
         ELSE NULL END AS 'TimeOut'
FROM
    #Date
CROSS JOIN
    TblEmployee
LEFT JOIN
    MachineRawPunch
ON
    MachineRawPunch.PAYCODE = TblEmployee.PAYCODE
AND
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MachineRawPunch.OFFICEPUNCH, 20) = #Date.PunchDate
GROUP BY
    #Date.PunchDate,
    TblEmployee.PAYCODE,
    TblEmployee.PRESENTCARDNO
ORDER BY
    #Date.PunchDate,
    TblEmployee.PAYCODE,
    TblEmployee.PRESENTCARDNO

DROP TABLE #Date
```

**Loop**

```
while (sqlReader.Read())
{
    // get the results of each column
    string date = (string)sqlReader["Date"];
    string cardNumber = sqlReader["CARDNO"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : (string)sqlReader["CARDNO"];
    DateTime inTime = sqlReader["TimeIn"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime)sqlReader["TimeIn"];
    DateTime outTime = sqlReader["TimeOut"] == DBNull.Value ? DateTime.MinValue : (DateTime)sqlReader["TimeOut"];
    string payCode = (string)sqlReader["PAYCODE"];

    //Stores single row as string 
    int hrsWorked = outTime == DateTime.MinValue ? 0 : outTime.Subtract(inTime).Hours;
    int minsWorked = outTime == DateTime.MinValue ? 0 : outTime.Subtract(inTime).Minutes;
    strRow = date + "," +
             payCode + "," +
             cardNumber + "," +
             (inTime == DateTime.MinValue ? string.Empty : inTime.ToString("H:mm")) + "," +
             (outTime == DateTime.MinValue ? string.Empty : outTime.ToString("H:mm")) + ", " +
             hrsWorked + "." + minsWorked + " , Staus";
    Console.WriteLine(strRow);
    //Write to file
    // sw.WriteLine(strRow);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: It will be very helpful if someone could provide the SQL query string. am stuck here plz help me

Comment: Please see my update.  You can also first put the rows between the two dates in a # table and then perform this logic on that subset, but then it might also be a good idea to do this in a stored procedure rather than inline SQL - for future readability and maintainability.

Comment: Thanks Veldmuis, Query is working fine, just one thing if somebody is absent, how it can display null in front of PAYCODE, currently absent records are not listing. I have stored Employee data in TblEmployee in other table with reference with PAYCODE

Comment: Please see the changes made to the SQL.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Please help me with looping, I have posted my loop in your answer, I am stuck with it since last 3 days, please help. This is my first project in .net, one more day left in deadline

Comment: @Saquib please don't ask questions by editing it into somebody else's answer. Just use the Ask Question button. Your loop can be found here: http://pastebin.com/pFP1cKqN. (Also, Veldmuis has no access to your edit anyway and couldn't possibly help you).

Comment: I changed your loop a bit to do the checks for nulls coming back from the DB.

Comment: @Veldmuis, I am getting Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DateTime'

Comment: Sorry about that - I left out the brackets.  Please see the latest edit

Comment: Thanks for quick response, please visit this link http://pastebin.com/f2eSzzgR I have pasted Output in CSV, which is not fine, I just added a WHERE clause in Query for active employee at Line number 35, please help

Comment: What exactly would you like to change?

Comment: Its missing the card number and some rows also, I have posted csv which is generated for daily report by current software, there are a huge difference in both you can see it at http://pastebin.com/b1ke0H6v

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13042/discussion-between-saquib-and-veldmuis)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
,       datediff(minute, first_in, last_out) as duration
from    (
        select  emp_reader_id
        ,       min(case when Event_entry.event_entry_name = 'IN' then trnevents.DT end) as first_in
        ,       max(case when Event_entry.event_entry_name = 'OUT' then trnevents.DT end) as last_out
        ,       cast(min(trnevents.DT) as date) as date
        from    trnevents inner join Event_entry on trnevents.EventCatId=Event_entry.EventCatId
        group by
                emp_reader_id
        ,       cast(trnevents.DT as date)
        ) as SubQueriesMustBeNamed
        select * from trnevents
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to do the min/max and grouping in Sql.

But just in case your sold on getting it done in code I would do something like this:

Create a method to return your data as enumerable rows:

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> ExecuteSelect()
{
  cmd = new SqlCommand();
  cmd.Connection = con;
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CARDNO, OFFICEPUNCH, PAYCODE FROM MachineRawPunch WHERE OFFICEPUNCH >= @p_StartDate AND OFFICEPUNCH <= @p_EndDate ORDER BY PAYCODE, OFFICEPUNCH";
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_StartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate.Date;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_EndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = endDate.Date.AddDays(1);

  using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (reader.Read()) yield return reader;
  }
}
```

Then in your export button click event do a nifty group with min and max using linq. You should be able to do the rest of the formatting and manipulation from here onwards:

```
private void buttonExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Selects the rows into a list of typed objects. Easier for querying below:
  var rows =
    ExecuteSelect().Select(
      r =>
      new
        {
          CardNo = (string) r["CARDNO"],
          OfficePunch = (DateTime) r["OFFICEPUNCH"],
          PayCode = (string) r["PAYCODE"]
        }).ToList();

  var groupedRows = (from r in rows
                     group r by new {r.CardNo, r.OfficePunch}
                     into g
                     select new
                              {
                                CardNo = g.Select(f => f.CardNo).FirstOrDefault(),
                                PayCode = g.Select(f => f.PayCode).FirstOrDefault(),
                                InDateTime = g.Min(min => min.OfficePunch),
                                OutDateTime = g.Max(max => max.OfficePunch)
                              }).ToList();

  foreach (var row in groupedRows)
  {
    //write to CSV
    //row.CardNo, row.PayCode, row.InDateTime, row.OutDateTime
  }
}
```

I hope this guides you in the right direction. Basically what's left is to format the dates as times and calculate the hours.

Comment: Thanks for your code, but its looping continuously with this code.
string resRow = "";

            foreach (var row in groupedRows)
            {
                //write to CSV
                //row.CardNo, row.PayCode, row.InDateTime, row.OutDateTime

                resRow += row.InDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "," + row.CardNo + "," + row.PayCode + "," + row.InDateTime.ToString("HH:MM") + ", " + row.OutDateTime.ToString("HH:MM")+ "\r\n";
                Console.WriteLine(resRow);
            }
            // Enable button

Comment: SQL query will be great, please help guys

Comment: What is the rowcount of groupedRows?

Answer (score 0):

Single query is enough:

```
select
    PAYCODE, CARDNO,
    min(officepunch) as INtime,
    max(officepunch) as OutTime,
    timediff(max(officepunch),min(officepunch)) as HRSWork 
FROM database.tablename 
group by CARDNO, PAYCODE, cast(officepunch as date) 
order by cardno;
```